# Calling setstate after processing forEach within useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to process some api data on useEffect and while processing data I need to set it on various states, while processing the data, for some reasons useEffect is getting triggered infinitely. Although from the class components I'm aware of setState being an asynchronous action which is not waiting for the completion of forEach. Do we have any workaround for functional components.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const apiResponse = fetchAppName();  
    apiResponse.then(
        (response) => {
          // if (response.statusCode === '200' && response.status.statusType === 'SUCCESS' && response.data) {
            const dataFields = {};
            const appNameValues = [];
            dummyData.data.forEach((ele) => {
              const workFlowIds = [];
              ele.workflowConfigs.forEach((wc) => {
                workFlowIds.push(wc.workflowId);
              })
              dataFields[ele.name] = workFlowIds;
            });
            Object.keys(dataFields).forEach((k) => {
              appNameValues.push(k);
            });
            setAppData(dataFields);
            setDropDownOptions({
              ...dropDownOptions,
              appName: appNameValues,
            });
          // }
      }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log('Failed to fetchAppNames due to: ', e);
      });
  },[setDropDownOptions, dropDownOptions]);
```

Comment: Don't put the setter in the dependencies array

Comment: Even after that it's being called infinitely @Jazz

Comment: When do you want the effect to run?

Comment: Your setting it and then calling it when it's set so it's creating a loop I think you should remove both dependencies

Comment: @DrewReese: I want to run this effect once the first forEach loop completes, basically calling setDropDownOptions on the completion of all forEach

Comment: That doesn't make any sense since the forEach loop ***is in*** the effect's callback. When do you want the effect's callback overall to run?

Comment: Got the point, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Don't use a dependency that is updated by the effect. In other words, `dropDownOptions` is a dependency and the effect updates it, thus creating a render loop.

## Solution

The state updater function is stable, so it's unnecessary, and use a functional state update to remove the other `dropDownOptions` dependency.

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
> or useCallback dependency list.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const apiResponse = fetchAppName();  
  apiResponse.then(
    (response) => {
      // if (response.statusCode === '200' && response.status.statusType === 'SUCCESS' && response.data) {
        const dataFields = {};
        const appNameValues = [];
        dummyData.data.forEach((ele) => {
          const workFlowIds = [];
          ele.workflowConfigs.forEach((wc) => {
            workFlowIds.push(wc.workflowId);
          })
          dataFields[ele.name] = workFlowIds;
        });
        Object.keys(dataFields).forEach((k) => {
          appNameValues.push(k);
        });
        setAppData(dataFields);
        setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions => ({
          ...dropDownOptions,
          appName: appNameValues,
        }));
      // }
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log('Failed to fetchAppNames due to: ', e);
    });
},[]); // will run on mount, add other dependency triggers if needed.
```

Comment: I had once read somewhere that setState is asynchronous as so the forEach loop. I was kind of thinking that maybe in the middle of the execution of first forEach the setDropDownOptions was called and then again the forEach loop continues the execution of rest of the context left hence forming a render loop. @DrewResse

Comment: @AshishBairwa `setState` and `useState` updater functions are completely synchronous functions, they enqueue (i.e. "request") state to be updated. React enqueued state updates *are* asynchronously processed. The forEach loop is also synchronous.

Comment: @DrewResse https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710